# How to update Tkinter Listbox text variable

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, raspberry-pi

I want to update an listbox data automatically. what's wrong with my code??

```
import Tkinter,time
from Tkinter import *
window=Tk()
box=Tkinter.Listbox(window,width=17,height=12,fg="black")
data=0
box.grid(row=0,column=0)
box.insert(Tkinter.END,data)
def monitor():
    global data
    print data
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        data=data+1
        box.update()
window.after(10,monitor)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: the listbox always showing 0. not changing.

Comment: That's because `box` pays no attention to the *name* of the object that was passed in.  It pays attention only to the object.  In fact, there is no way for it to know that that the name of the object is `data`.  When you say `data=data+1`, you aren't modifying the object itself; you are making `data` refer to a different number.  You need to re-insert `data`.  I'm guessing that would mean `box.delete(Tkinter.END); box.insert(Tkinter.END, data)`

Comment: is there any way to update data without delete and insert???

Comment: I don't know.  You might try using a `Tkinter.IntVar` instead of an integer, but I don't have a whole lot of experience with `Tkinter`, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

First of all please be consistent with your code.

- Use one kind of import for one library

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Second, `while True` constructs are to be ommitted if possible.
You used window.after in your main routine, why not do that in your monitor function as well?

```
def monitor():
    global data


    # do the work that needs to be done...

    # after uses ms, to calling monitor 
    # after 1000 ms is the same as calling 
    # sleep(1) in your while true construct
    window.after(1000, monitor)
```

Finally, zodo is right, you need to update the listbox data by e.g. delete / insert combination.

```
import Tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
box = tk.Listbox(window, width=17, height=12, fg="black")
data = 0
box.grid(row=0, column=0)
box.insert(tk.END, data)

def monitor():
    global data

    print data

    data = data + 1
    # Update the listbox
    # 1. clear all
    box.delete(0, tk.END)
    # 2. insert new data
    box.insert(tk.END, data)
    window.after(1000, monitor)

window.after(10, monitor)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to declare box or window as global.

Comment: That is interesting for me - how is that, Bryan?

Comment: Python automatically exposes global variables inside functions. You only need to declare them if you modify the variables. When you call `box.delete` you aren't modifying the variable, you're just calling a method on the object. https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Comment: I adapted the answer and removed the global part